# highlight the treeNode in the Jtree using the treeNode itself

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` (**myTree**) and in another class, I have a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` which was taken from **myTree**.

In a certain function, I want the `JTree` to highlight the node.

***I tried:***

```
myTree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(treeNode));
```

but visually nothing is happening.

any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I have also another `JTable` which is rendered based on the selected `treeNode` in **myTree**. The table is updating **correctly**. It's just the **myTree** which refused to update visually.

Comment: Is the tree focused at the time the function is called?  I would not need to ask if you'd posted an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, Actually the focus is in another JTree. Sorry I cannot post more code because it is highly confidential. I don't know if I am permitted to post a question here :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the actual tree path of the node. Not just an instance of TreePath:

```
myTree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(treeModel.getPathToRoot(treeNode)));
```

Also, the javadoc says:

> If any component of the path is hidden (under a collapsed node), and getExpandsSelectedPaths is true it is exposed (made viewable)

So make sure that `getExpandsSelectedPaths` is true.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. I think it has something to do with the fact that the tree is not focused like @AndrewThompson suggested

Comment: Sorry, it was a minor bug elsewhere

Comment: @AdelBoutros: are you aware that the answer you just accepted says exactly the same thing as my answer? It's been half an hour that I gave you the solution.

Comment: I read your answer many times, and yes you are right. At first it looked different. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: See my answer below which incorporates this one.

Answer (score 4):

From the java API, we get the description of TreePath below:

> Represents a path to a node. A TreePath is an array of Objects that are vended from a TreeModel. **The elements of the array are ordered such that the root is always the first element (index 0) of the array**.

so, a valid TreePath must be constructed from an array including all nodes on the path from the root node and the node you want to select.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't notice that @JBNizet replied first. You will get an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Many Swing bugs, quirks and other shortcomings can be worked around using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // JB Nizet's solution:
        myTree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(treeModel.getPathToRoot(treeNode)));
    }
});
```

This also solves the same problem with [JTree.setSelectionPaths(TreePath[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setSelectionPaths%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%5b%5d%29).